# How to insert latitude & longitude to form automatically when the marker clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I make map with google api v3. I make form inside info window, it appears when the marker clicked. Here is map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var marker;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.9667, 110.41677);
      var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
      var html = "<form action='save.php' method='post'>" +
         "Title: <input type='text' name='title' id='title'/></br>" +
         "Latitude: <input type='text' name='latitude' id='latitude'/></br>" +
         "Longitude: <input type='text' name='longitude' id='longitude'/></br>" +
         "Description: <input type='text' name='description' id='description'/></br>" +
         "Category: <input type='text' name='category' id='category'/></br>" +
             "<input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' /></br>" +
        "</form>";
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    });
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

What I want is when the marker clicked, latitude & longitude forms are automatically filled, like this picture
[image]

Anyone can help me? Thank you for any help

Comment: btw - after adjusting the whitespace in your code it looks like you have a `listener` inside another `listener`.  I'm guessing this was not your intention...

Comment: yes there is listener inside another listener. I have inserted your piece of code inside the listener but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the marker that was clicked and from the position you can get the lat/long coordinates

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
    latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
    longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click listener function for the marker, add another event listener for the infowindow domready event (will fire once the infowindow is open and part of the DOM).  Then get the latitude and longitude of the marker and put it in the form:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready',function() {
     document.getElementById('latitude').value=marker.getPosition().lat();
     document.getElementById('longitude').value=marker.getPosition().lng();
  });
});
```